# Ways of initializing arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, initializing

I'd like to know the different ways for initializing an Array in C, because i'm having a little problem when trying to do something...

Im starting programming in C in college, its the first language, and we are viewing pointers and some functions.

That said, I was trying the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    char a[][10] = {"Hola","Chau"};
    char b[][10] = {*a[0],*a[1]};
    printf("Contenido de &a es: %s \n",&a);
    printf("Contenido de &b es: %s \n",&b);
    system("pause");
}
```

Which is copying what is inside a[0][0 ... 10] but wont work... at least in MS VS 2010 that is what we use at college.

So I'd like to know a link to a reference of the different ways possibles for initializing an array.

Searching here in stack, I've found the memcpy function and this work this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    char a[5] = {"Hola"};
    char b[5];
    memcpy(b,a,3); /* testing */
    b[3] = '\0'; /* testing */
    printf("Contenido de &a es: %s \n",&a);
    printf("Contenido de &b es: %s \n",&b);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: memcpy doesn't initialize the array, it assigns.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish array assignment(e.g., memcpy, or use while/for loop to assign elements in array one-by-one, whatever) with array initialization. Array can only be initialized in its definition line.

Check out here for two ways to specify initializers for arrays: [initialization of arrays](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/aryin.htm).

Comment: Hmmm not sure if you understood me, I'd like to initialize an array with a value from other array.....